# issue on Google map polyline

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

now i am worked on tracking application project.but i Don't Know how to draw polyline in my page i m write run the code i am getting no result.
here this my code
i getting the data dynamically.

```
      var customLabel = {
        IN : {
          label: 'I'

        },
        <?php foreach ($datas as $key => $value) {?>
        CON_<?php echo ($key+1);?> : {
          label: '<?php  echo ($key+1); ?>'

        },
        <?php } ?>
        OUT : {
          label:'O'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(11.0168, 76.9558),
          zoom: 20
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('mapxml.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              //var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = type//address view
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
             // alert(type);
              if(type == 'IN')
              {
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                 icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png',
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
            }
            else if( type == 'OUT')
            {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                 icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
            }
            else
            {
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                 icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png',
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
            }


                    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  path: markerElem,
                    geodesic: true,
                    strokeColor: "#e0223f",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: "#0000FF",
                    fillOpacity: 0.4
                   });
                 flightPath.setMap(map);


              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });

        }
```

any idea whats the issue about?

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you do `path: markerElem`, but the path needs to just be an array of LatLng coordinates, which `markerElem` isn't.

Secondly, you're looping over all the `markers`, creating a Marker for each.  And within that loop, you're trying to create a polyline.

Instead you need to create the polyline after the loop.  Have an array of the points you need to draw the polyline for, that you append each marker's LatLng coordinates into, and then draw the line after the loop.

Something like this:

```
  function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(11.0168, 76.9558),
          zoom: 20
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      var path = [];

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('mapxml.php', function(data) {
          var xml = data.responseXML;
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              //var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              path.push(point);

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = type //address view
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              // alert(type);
              if (type == 'IN') {
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png',
                      position: point,
                      label: icon.label
                  });
              } else if (type == 'OUT') {
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
                      position: point,
                      label: icon.label
                  });
              } else {
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png',
                      position: point,
                      label: icon.label
                  });
              }

              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                  infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
          });

          var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: path,
              geodesic: true,
              strokeColor: "#e0223f",
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              fillColor: "#0000FF",
              fillOpacity: 0.4,
              map: map
          });
      });

  }
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)